# How to type properties in merging object for getInitialState of createEntityAdapter object?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, createentityadapter

I want to type status with FetchingStatus type. How to implement that?

```
type FetchingStatus = 'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed';

const initialState = companyPagesAdapter.getInitialState({
        status: 'idle',
        perPage: 1,
        lastPage: 1
    });
```

here is signature of getInitialState:

```
getInitialState<S extends object>(state: S): EntityState<T> & S
```

Comment: share your companyPagesAdapter object and getInitialState method

Comment: @captain-yossarian, Btw, those are not mine, those are implemented by redux developers. I added getInitialState signature, I guess it is impossible to impelent, bruh moment

Comment: it is possible...createEntityAdapter excepts a generic

Comment: @AshwynHorton, but the generic is not destined for the merge object we pass in getInitialState method, is it?

Comment: I actually tried doing this myself, and I see what you mean...interesting, I get a string cast to ```Status``` error...

Comment: It only works if i add a type assertion

Answer (score 0):

```
type FetchingStatus = "idle" | "loading" | "succeeded" | "failed";
    
    
interface ExtendedEntityAdapterState {
    status: FetchingStatus
    perPage: number,
    lastPage: number
}

const initialState: ExtendedEntityAdapterState   = {
  status: 'idle',
  perPage: 1,
  lastPage: 1
});

companyPagesAdapter.getInitialState(initialState)
```

Something like this worked for me.
Reducer action gives correct constraints.